# Combine multiple Json objects into one?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am stuck on creating a single json object and hope someone can help.

```
def loadit():
r = sess.get(url)
data = r.json()
z = data['styles']
for zz in z:
    ID = zz['id']
    color = zz['name']
    sizes = zz['sizes']
    for s in sizes:
        stock = s['stock_level']
        size = s['name']
        ids = s['id']
        logit(stock,size,ids,ID,color)

def logit(stock,size,ids,ID,color):
    stock = stock
    size = size
    ids = ids
    ID = ID
    color = color
    data = {ID: []}
    arr = [{'Color':color,'Size':size,'Stock':stock}]
    data[ID].append(arr)
    o = json.dumps(data)
```

I want these looping objects into 1 json thats easy to parse per ID

```
   {"21239": [[{"Color": "Pale Yellow", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Large"}]]}
   {"21239": [[{"Color": "Pale Yellow", "Stock": 0, "Size": "XLarge"}]]}
   {"21240": [[{"Color": "Red", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Small"}]]}
   {"21240": [[{"Color": "Red", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Medium"}]]}
   {"21240": [[{"Color": "Red", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Large"}]]}
   {"21240": [[{"Color": "Red", "Stock": 0, "Size": "XLarge"}]]}
   {"21241": [[{"Color": "Terra Cotta", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Small"}]]}
   {"21241": [[{"Color": "Terra Cotta", "Stock": 0, "Size": "Medium"}]]}
```

Comment: You do not have "json objects". What you have are dictionaries. Where do they come from? What is the expected output?

Comment: @DYZ added json.dumps sorry.

Comment: Are you aware that your whole function can be replaced with `return {ID:[[{'Color':color,'Size':size,'Stock':stock}]]}`? It returns a single-item dictionary. We need to know how it is called to assist with combining the dictionaries into one dictionary.

Comment: @DYZ I updated the original post

Comment: Your function `logit` does not return anything. If you want to process the result produced by the function, you must return it. I strongly suggest that your fix that function first (as I mentioned above, the whole body of the function can be replaced with one statement.) The way your function is implemented now, no further processing is possible.

Comment: If i did this return (stock,size,ids,ID,color) in loadit(), it will return the very first object only